# YouTube Data API - Resumable Uploads - Start a resumable session - Errors

Tags: upload, youtube, resume-upload

Running into parseError attempting to follow the "start a resumable session" YouTube Data API - Resumable Uploads documentation.

complete list of efforts ,response and code

1. I read on the Google APIs - "Global domain errors" page "parseError The API server cannot parse the request body."
2. I have watched "YouTube Developers Live: Debugging & Dealing with Errors" still know clue there
3. I have read "stack over flow" for similar questions, but never get answered,or answers are still un clear
4. the test youtube account i want to upload to has a youtube channel with videos
5. I tried the client PHP upload API, but found out later its not a resumable upload.
6. I thought resumable upoad would be a better option, so i dont frustrate users, by wasting there time,if there connection drops out....
7. I am runing PHP from hostgator account
8. I noticed how when i did not get an error, it would return the regular snippet and status data and not the "Step 2 - Save the resumable session URI" data
9. I am using long lived access tokens pulled from my database...in the requests, the youtube user has a channel with videos before i stored the access tokens
10. I do check the access tokens with tokeninfo?
11. I noticed changing "uploadType" to "uploadtype" would produce  "message": "Media type 'application/json; charset=utf-8'

is not supported. Valid media types: [video/*, application/octet-stream]",following this error by changing content type to "application/octet-stream" would return "kind = youtube#video
object with json snippet,status" not the Step 2 - Save the resumable session URI, so i changed things back to "uploadType" and "application/json; charset=utf-8" now facing same parse error

12. I notice in the docs "Parameter values in the request URL must be URL-encoded." when i would urlencode() "Parameter values" it would return errors or parseError when i removed the urlencode function
13. Even changing "Host: www.googleapis.com" to "Host: https://www.googleapis.com" would produce "The requested URL /upload/youtube/v3/videos was not found on this server.  That’s all we know."
14. parse error appears to be most persistent so far
15. I have changed urlencode() to rawurlencode() still parse error
16. i would add charset=utf-8;multipart/form-data;application/octet-stream to content type header, still parse error
17. I notice content type on string is text/plain; charset=us-ascii not sure if google server expects pure application/json

any help would be great…

```
  Array
  (
      [response] => Array
          (
              [0] => {
   "error": {
    "errors": [
     {
      "domain": "global",
      "reason": "parseError",
      "message": "Parse Error"
     }
    ],
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Parse Error"
   }
  }

          )

      [headers] => [
      "POST \/upload\/youtube\/v3\/videos?uploadType=resumable&part=snippet,status HTTP\/1.1",
      "Host: www.googleapis.com",
      "Authorization: Bearer ya29.vAAY5n3SJq3uCG7z4tOhehDxYj9Z7mxFENtD5PKF_dJqFlLqwCktRHTrEJkUgY_NrJD3KMetKeBA_w",
      "Content-Length: 303",
      "Content-Type: application\/json; charset=utf-8",
      "X-Upload-Content-Length: 20121",
      "X-Upload-Content-Type: video\/*"
  ]
      [curl_resource] => Resource id #18
      [video_aray] => {
      "snippet": {
          "title": "test video",
          "description": "testing api",
          "tags": [
              "any",
              "thing"
          ],
          "categoryId": 25
      },
      "status": {
          "privacyStatus": "public",
          "embeddable": true,
          "license": "youtube"
      }
  }
      [json_requestbody] => {
      "snippet": {
          "title": "test video",
          "description": "testing api",
          "tags": [
              "any",
              "thing"
          ],
          "categoryId": 25
      },
      "status": {
          "privacyStatus": "public",
          "embeddable": true,
          "license": "youtube"
      }
  }
      [request_url] => https://www.googleapis.com/upload/youtube/v3/videos?uploadType=resumable&part=snippet,status
      [content_type_of_request] => text/plain; charset=us-ascii
      [0] => text/plain; charset=us-ascii
      [1] => text/plain; charset=us-ascii
  )
```

Source

```
 public function startResumableSession()
    {
            $videoResource = array( 'snippet'=>array('title'=>"test video",'description'=>"testing api",
                                    'tags'=>array("any","thing"),'categoryId'=>25),
                                    'status'=>array('privacyStatus'=>"public",'embeddable'=>True,'license'=>"youtube"));
            $requestBody = json_encode($videoResource,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
            $headers = array
              (

                "POST /upload/youtube/v3/videos?uploadType=resumable&part=snippet,status HTTP/1.1",
                "Host: www.googleapis.com",
                "Authorization: Bearer ya29.vAAY5n3SJq3uCG7z4tOhehDxYj9Z7mxFENtD5PKF_dJqFlLqwCktRHTrEJkUgY_NrJD3KMetKeBA_w",
                "Content-Length: ".strlen($requestBody),
                "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8",
                "X-Upload-Content-Length: 20121",
                "X-Upload-Content-Type: video/*"
            );
            /* Parameter values in the request URL must be URL-encoded. */
            $url = "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/youtube/v3/videos?uploadType=resumable&part=snippet,status"; 
            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$headers);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,urlencode($requestBody));
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,TRUE);
            $result = curl_exec($ch);
            $json = json_decode($result);
            /* Check request body contenttype */
            $finfo = new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME);
            $t1=  $finfo->buffer($requestBody);
            $t2 = $finfo->buffer("test");
            $t3 = $finfo->buffer(utf8_encode("test"));
            /* debug info */
            return array(   'response'=>(array)$result,
                            'headers'=>json_encode($headers,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT),
                            'curl_resource'=>$ch,
                            'video_aray'=>json_encode($videoResource,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT),
                            'json_requestbody'=>$requestBody,
                            'request_url'=>$url,
                            'content_type_of_request'=>$t1,$t2,$t3
                        );
    }
```

Comment: Yeah the request works but does not return the location link....

"Resumable Upload Youtube api V3, status 200 and not return URI to upload the file"
Someone had the same problem back in May...and question goes unanswered, makes you wonder what people really do at YouTube and Google..what a waste of time...screw this am gonna try vimeo upload api, at least they have tech support....

Answer (score -1):

Easy answer is - you do it wrong.

You are NOT supposed to add "POST", "Host:" and "Content-Length:" into $headers because that is generated by curl (CURLOPT_URL and CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS).

YouTube API works correctly. It is not their fault.

Comment: this is not an answer. sorry